# Autosys job which is executing .cmd file taking longer time than running .cmd script separately through command line interface

Tags: windows, performance, cmd, delayed-job, autosys

This job calls .cmd script which calls a product in another environment to execute.
While running in that product tool,it was taking around 11 mins to save the file
But while calling the product I'm autosys through .cmd scripy.,it was taking around 40mins .

Comment: Can you please show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: From the Autosys tag _Unless you are asking a programming question about integration with the AutoSys SDK, your question is likely off-topic. Questions about the use of server management software should be directed to Server Fault._

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to execute autosys job for which the command is .cmd script.
In JIL,command was defined such that it runs the .cmd script
For example ,consider test.cmd which is windows batch script.

In test.cmd script , code was written like below

Call  C\users\software.exe /product "productinsoft"

From the above line, software.exe is one software and productinsoft is etl  item in that software which generates .CSV file in its own server path.

While running this through autosys,by calling in the above pattern
Job is taking more time to complete for read/write operations.
But when the etl item is executed through the software manually it is taking lesser time.